# ffmpeg doesn't accept input in script

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg

this is a beginner's question but i can't figure out the answer after looking into it for several days:

I want ffmpeg to extract the audio portion of a video and save it in an .ogg container. If i run the following command in terminal it works as expected:

```
ffmpeg -i example.webm -vn -acodec copy example.ogg
```

For convenience, i want to do this in a script. However, if i pass a variable to ffmpeg it apparently just considers the first word and produces the error "No such file or directory".

I noticed that my terminal escapes spaces by a \ so i included this in my script. This doesn't solve the problem though.

Can someone please explain to me, why ffmpeg doesn't consider the whole variable that is passed to it in a script while working correctly when getting passed the same content in the terminal?

This is my script that passes the filename with spaces escaped by \ to ffmpeg:

```
#!/bin/bash

titelschr=$(echo $@ | sed "s/ /\\\ /g")
titelohne=$(echo $titelschr | cut -d. -f 1)
titelogg=$(echo -e ${titelohne}.ogg)  

ffmpeg -i $titelschr -vn -acodec copy $titelogg
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote variable expansions, try this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

titelschr=$1
titelogg="${titelschr%.*}.ogg"

ffmpeg -i "$titelschr" -vn -acodec copy "$titelogg"
```

call with :

```
bash test.sh "Some video file.mp4"
```

This way, you don't need to escape spaces.

Comment: Quoting the variables when passing them to ffmpeg solved my problem. Thank you very much!

I didn't see this explained in any guide i googled, maybe because it's so basic that it seems obvious to everyone.